# Order of zero for $\sin(z^2)$ about $z=\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What's the order of the zero $z=\sqrt{\pi}$ for the complex function $f(z)=\sin{(z^2)}$?

Here my take... Letting $w = z^2$ such that $f(w)=\sin w$, we want the order of the zero $w=\pi$. Expanding about $w=\pi$ gives

$$\begin{align}
\sin(w) &= \sin(\pi) + \cos(\pi)(w-\pi) - \sin(\pi)(w-\pi)^2 + \mathcal{O(3)} \\
&= -(w-\pi) + \mathcal{O(3)} \\\\
\sin(z^2)&= -(z^2-\pi) + \mathcal{O(3)}
\end{align}$$

I guess I'm a bit confused about the definition of order here. From my understanding, the order ought to be equal to the first nonzero coefficient in the Taylor expansion. Wouldn't that make the coefficient $c_1=-1$... and that would make it order... one?

But if the order is ascribed to the coefficient of the first *term* (not Taylor term but term in the traditional sense), then why does it seem that my function has a constant term?? This would prevent a zero altogether!

Maybe I should have expanding about $z=\sqrt{\pi}$ the old fashioned way...

Comment: The order is not the first nonzero coefficient, but the degree of the first nonzero term.

Comment: The zero is of order 1, since $\sin(\pi)=0$. If it were $\sin^n(z^2)$, then it would be a zero of order $n$.